# How is Verilog's macro_text split into tokens?

Tags: parsing, verilog, standards, system-verilog

From my reading of IEEE 1800-2017, it seems that lexing is context-dependent, notably due to numbers. Consider the following examples.

```
// A number followed by an identifier -- delayed invocation of task `f`
# 1f;

// A number followed by a null statement.
#'h 1f;
```

Whether `f` is part of the preceding numeric token depends on whether the numeric token is preceded by `'h`.

However, when preprocessing, the context is not always clear. What should the following snippet print?

```
module m;
    initial begin
        `define Y(f) 1f
        $display('h `Y(c));
    end
endmodule
```

Should `1f` inside the *macro_text* be treated as two tokens and `f` be substituted for `c` (with `'h1c` getting printed), or should `1f` be treated as a single token, making the macro parameter unused (and the $display argument `'h1f`)?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but it seems that the tools don't agree either. If you try it on https://www.edaplayground.com, different tools give different results.

You might already know that it's possible to force the `f` to be replaced. The following works the same across tools:

```
module m;
    initial begin
      `define Y(f) 1``f``
      $display("%x", 'h `Y(c));
    end
endmodule
```

The extra backticks force the preprocessor to interpret `f` as the macro argument and to fuse it to `1`. (I took  the liberty of also adding a format specifier for the display to make the printed text easier to read.)

Comment: Right, I noticed that the tools disagree and I find the text of the Standard vague -- I was wondering if I'm missing some clarifying paragraph somewhere.